# Previously working SSH configuration no longer works

Tags: windows, ssh, gitlab

I had ssh configured to connect to Gitlab for a long time, and somehow everything quit working.

- I've completely deleted everything in the .ssh folder and recreated everything while following the GitLab guide, and it still gives me an error.
- I've uninstalled and reinstalled OpenSSH.

```
ssh -Tvvv git@gitlab.com:USERNAME
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
debug1: Reading configuration data C:\\Users\\WINUSERNAME/.ssh/config
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2
debug2: resolve_addr: could not resolve name gitlab.com:USERNAME as address: No such host is known.
debug1: resolve_canonicalize: hostname gitlab.com:USERNAME is an unrecognised address
debug2: resolving "gitlab.com:USERNAME" port 22
ssh: Could not resolve hostname gitlab.com:USERNAME: No such host is known.
```

Config File:

```
# GitLab.com
Host gitlab.com
  PreferredAuthentications publickey
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub
```

I'm not sure what else I can do to resolve the issue.

Comment: There is **NO `:USERNAME`** in the `ssh` command format; see examples at https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/#verify-that-you-can-connect .

Comment: I've also tried ssh -T git@gitlab.username.com

(I should clarify, I'm using my gitlab username in place of "username").

Comment: The `@name` must be a valid domain name (aka DNS name) of the server. Unless you have registered your username as a domain name, which is extremely unlikely, your username is not a valid domain name of any server, much less the server run by gitlab, so don't use it. **As the examples in the gitlab doc show, you do not put your username in the `ssh` command at all.** If you are using a private (e.g. company-run) server, substitute the name of the _server_, not your username.